# aspnet-codegenerator could not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am following a basic TodoList API tutorial for .Net Core 3.1 SDK from the Microsoft docs. I have reached this point in the tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-code#scaffold-a-controller

After gloabally installing the aspnet-codegenerator tool, making sure it is in the correct path 'User.dotnet\tools', trying older versions, restarting VScode and powershell, it still gives the following error:

"Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be
found on the PATH."

I am attempting to scaffold a todo controller with the following command:
"dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name TodoItemsController -async -api -m TodoItem -dc TodoContext -outDir Controllers"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've added these NuGet packages to the project you are using as startup project.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

Comment: I have done this already per the tutorial. Unfortunately it doesnt work.

Comment: Is your `'User.dotnet\tools'` directory in PATH ?

Comment: I am very new to c#, how do I check that, and what exactly is path? I did install it specifically to that path if that's what your asking.

Answer (score 2):

I was using VSCodes terminal and that couldnt find the tool. When I used my cmd for my windows machine, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 3.1.5
```

Then I can:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name ValuesController -async -api --readWriteActions -outDir Controllers
```

BUT be aware of versions mismatch between "dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator" and ".NETCoreApp,Version": https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator/

In newer versions this might be the solution: `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 5.0.2`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help a few in a situation similar to mine.  I also was following this same tutorial and got a bit stuck at the "Scaffold a Controller" step.

I discovered for some reason that my NuGet Package sources was configured in "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" mode only.  Apparently, this is the default (??) configuration for certain installs of the full edition of Visual Studio.

In turn (following the VS Code steps in the tutorial), when entering this command:

> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator

it was failing with an error message because my (local) version of this package was indeed old and incompatible with the ***netcoreapp3.1*** target framework.

To fix this... I opened up the full Visual Studio IDE and navigated to:

- Tools -->  NuGet Package Manager --> Package Manager Settings --> Package Sources
- Added a new entry with a name of "Nuget Online" and pointed it to the source of: - https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

[Picture of NuGet Package Manager Settings - Under Package Source Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMvnZ.png)

With NuGet now properly configured to check the online site...  I re-executed the above command in the VS Code - Terminal window and it correctly pulled in the necessary package.   I was able to proceed with the subsequent steps in the tutorial (including the generation of the TodoItemsController class).

Comment: Note: This same change can also be applied directly in the NuGet.Config file. Visual Studio was utilized for illustrative purposes. This file can typically be found at c:\users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Confg. Add an entry in the <packageSources> section: `<add key="Nuget Online" value="api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this package worked for me.

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 5.0.2
```

then generated the controller from CLI in Visual Studio CodeIDE as below:

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name MoviesController -m Movie -dc MvcMovieContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries
```

also check the below added in public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services):

```
services.AddDbContext<MvcMovieContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MvcMovieContext")));
```